# I can't catch "media:content url" . From rss feed response in Node.js

Tags: node.js, rss-reader

This is my url https://feeds.feedburner.com/ndtvnews-india-news.

I am trying this
And here is my node.js code

```
let feed = await parser.parseURL(rssFeedUrl);
console.log(feed.title);

    feed.items.forEach(item => {   
  console.log(item['media:content']);    
 });
```

I got the response

> {
> title: '6 Involved In Parliament Smoke Scare, 4 Arrested, 2 On The Run: Sources',
> link: 'https://www.ndtv.com/india-news/parliament-attack-6-involved-in-parliament-smoke-scare-4-arrested-2-on-the-run-sources-4666760',
> pubDate: 'Wed, 13 Dec 2023 17:20:33 +0530',
> 'content:encoded': '
>
> Six people ......
>
> ',
> guid: 'https://www.ndtv.com/india-news/parliament-attack-6-involved-in-parliament-smoke-scare-4-arrested-2-on-the-run-sources-4666760',
> isoDate: '2023-12-13T11:50:33.000Z'
> }

Here "media:content url" is not available